# Firestore return true when data is retrieved (Wait fore data to get send)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have a little problem with this code:

```js
  function usernameExists(username) {
    const result = db.collection('users').where("username", "==", username).get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          console.log("true");
          return true;
        });
        console.log("false");
        return false;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        return error.message;
    });
  }
```

So the problem is it never comes to the Point where it could return true or false, it just returns undefined, but it sends the console.log true when the username exists and false when its not already taken.
How can i wait untill the data is recieved?

Comment: Please show how you are using `usernameExists`  function or share portion of code if possible.

Comment: atm like that: 
console.log(usernameExists("Test"));
I just want to see if a username is already taken

Comment: You need to make function using async await to get such type response. Ref : https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/async-await-javascript-5038668ec6eb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you don't return the [promises chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining). You should do along the following lines:

```
  function usernameExists(username) {
    return db.collection('users').where("username", "==", username).get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          console.log("true");
          // Do something
        });
        // return something;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        return error.message;
    });
  }
```

---

For example:

```
  function usernameExists(username) {
    return db.collection('users').where("username", "==", username).get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        const theReturnedArray = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          console.log("true");
          theReturnedArray.push(doc.get("theField"));
        });
        return theReturnedArray;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        return error.message;
    });
  }
```

---

Or, since you said in the comments "I just want to see if a username is already taken":

```
  function usernameExists(username) {
    return db.collection('users').where("username", "==", username).get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
           return false;
        } else {
           return true;
        } 
    })
    .catch(error => {
        return error.message;
    });
  }
```

---

Note that `usernameExists()` itself is an asynchronous function, so you need to use [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) or async/await:

```
 usernameExists(username)
     .then(result => {
           console.log(result);
     });
```